# Mongodb aggregation query returns undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to get comments from the comments collection by matching the book id field in the book collection. Here's my aggregation query,

```
static async getBookByID(id) {

return await books.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup:
          {
            from: "Comments",
            let: { 'book_id': id },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match:
                  { $expr: { $eq: ['$book_id', '$$book_id'] } }
              },
               { $project: { 'title': 1, 'comments': 1 } },
              {
                $sort: {
                  'date': -1
                }
              }
            ],
            as: 'comments'
          }
        }
      ]);
}
```

My test is failing with

```
 Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received undefined.
```

**EDIT**

Comments collection,

```
{"_id":"5a9427658b0beebeb696b14d",
"name":"John Bishop",
"email":"john@fakegmail.com",
"book_id":"573a13a6f29313caabd17bd5",
"text":"Sed odit incidunt totam dolorem nam doloribus. Dignissimos dolore accusamus vel. Cupiditate deserunt esse quisquam quisquam cum.",
"date":"1976-03-16T19:54:28.000Z"}
```

Book Collection,

```
{"_id":"573a13a6f29313caabd17bd5","title":"Once Upon a Time in Mexico"}
```

Comment: Is the id defined? console the id parameter

Comment: Console your `id`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet console id shows 573a13a6f29313caabd17bd5.

Comment: @RajanSharma console id shows 573a13a6f29313caabd17bd5

Comment: Convert it to objectId. `{ 'book_id': ObjectId(id) }`

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyWinzlet . I have done that. Query runs but i am getting results for another book. I have added sample data for the comments and book collections in the question. Could you take a look and tell me where i am going wrong. I have spent quite a long time trying to figure this out.

Comment: Please ask a new question with the proper explanation.